# SQL: UPDATE query error value being used for column

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

I have a PHP sql command that updates a record.

```
$tsql = "UPDATE cplinktable SET bmsid = $bmsid, autotaskid = $autotaskid, waspdb = $waspdb, cpid = $cpid WHERE id = $id";
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Invalid column name 'WaspTrackAsset_SFT'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'WaspTrackAsset_SFT'. ) )
```

Is there some reason that the value of waspdb is being used as a column?

thanks,

Jonesy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a string field or varchar probably and you need it in single quotes. Like this:

```
$tsql = "UPDATE cplinktable SET bmsid = $bmsid, autotaskid = $autotaskid, waspdb = '$waspdb', cpid = $cpid WHERE id = $id"
```

Answer (score 3):

If the variable is a string, SQL requires single quotes around it:

```
waspdb = '$waspdb'
```

Otherwise, it will look in the source row for a column with the name of the value of `$wasdb`.  The reason why is perhaps most clearly illustrated with an example query:

```
update YourTable set col1 = 2*col2
```

This multiplies `col2` by `2`; it doesn't set `col1` to `'2*col2'` :)